# How to Convert 2 Varchar strings into a DateTime in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two vchar fields that contain date and time separately as text/string.

i.e 
Fdate(YYYYmmdd): 20170402
Ftime(HHmmss): 103101

How would I go about concatenating them and converting into a Datetime?

Converting the date can be done, but the issue I run into is when adding the time to it.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: What version of SQL Server? From 2012 upwards, `[DATE]TIME[2]FROMPARTS` is/are your friends here (they're more flexible than trying to massage your string into a form `CONVERT` accepts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `stuff()` to convert *varchar* time format to *datetime* format  :

```
select Fdate + cast(stuff(stuff(Ftime, 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':') as datetime) as datetime
```

Comment: Thank you - this worked exactly for what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
Select cast (substring(Fdate,0,5)+'-'+ 
             substring(Fdate,5,2)+'-'+ 
             substring(Fdate,7,2) 
        + ' ' + 
             substring(Ftime,0,3) + ':' + 
             substring(Ftime,3,2) + ':' + 
             substring(Ftime,5,2) 
       as datetime)
```

Output :

```
yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss
```

Comment: String indexing in T-SQL is 1-based, not 0-based. While `SUBSTRING(x, 0, 5)` is legal, it's less clear than the equivalent `SUBSTRING(x, 1, 4)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATETIMEFROMPARTS (  substring('20170402',1,4) , substring('20170402',5,2), substring('20170402',7,2), substring('103101',1,2), substring('103101',3,2), substring('103101',5,2) ,  substring('103101',7,2) )
```

output

```
2017-04-02 10:31:01.000
```